# Postgresql performing partitioning to find time difference

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to fill column D and column E.

- Column A: varchar(64) - unique for each trip
- Column B: smallint
- Column C: timestamp without time zone (excel messed it up in the
  image below but you can assume this as timestamp column)
- Column D: numeric - need to find out time from origin in minutes
- column E: numeric - time to destination in minutes.

Each trip has got different intermediate stations and I am trying to figure out the time it has been since origin and time to destination

1. Cell D2 = C2 - C2 = 0
2. cell D3 = C3 - C2
3. Cell D4 = C4 - C2
4. Cell E2 = E6 - E2
5. Cell E3 = E6 - E3
6. Cell E6 = E6 - E6 = 0

The main issue is that each trip contains differnt number of stations for each trip_id. I can think about using partition by column but cant figure out how to implement it.

Another sub question: I am dealing with very large table (100 million rows). What is the best way Postgresql experts implement data modification. Do you create like a sample table from the original data and implement everything on the sample before implementing the modifications on the original table or do you use something like "Begin trasaction" on the original data so that you can rollback in case of any error.

PS: Help with question title appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to know the number of stops

```
with a as (select *,extract(minutes from c - min(c) over (partition by a)) dd,extract(minutes from max(c) over (partition by a) - c) ee from td)
update td set d=dd, e=ee
from a
where a.a = td.a and a.b=td.b
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c9112/1